# How do use use Picasso library while downloading images from Amazon S3?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, picasso

I am storing my images on Amazon S3. I use the following code to download image from Amazon S3

```
 S3ObjectInputStream content = s3Client.getObject("bucketname", url).getObjectContent();
                byte[] bytes ;
                bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(content);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
                bitmap = CommonUtilities.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bitmap, 30);
                cache.put(url, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
                return bitmap;
```

While going through Picasso documentation, I read that to load images we simply need to do

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

So how to download Amazon S3 images through Picasso.

Comment: you have not upvoted any answer.. are you serious about using SO and helping others ? we have no clue as to what worked for you..

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`AmazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(String, String, Date)`](http://integ-docs-aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#generatePresignedUrl(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Date)) to generate a presigned url and pass it to Picasso. Here is an example ["Generate a Pre-signed Object URL using AWS SDK for Java"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html). Though the example is for the Java SDK, it's applicable for the AWS Android SDK.

Comment: That's nice method. Didn't know AWS SDK has it. :)

Comment: Be careful that the presigned url changes every time Amazon S3 credentials expires (key changes). So Picasso will load images again from network and not from cache. You should keep a map of your presigned urls. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354601/setting-key-for-picasso-for-s3-amazon

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `InputStream` of the `S3Object`, which will give bytes representation of that object. Instead, you need to build URI from to the `S3Object`. As far as I know the url is build in following manner:

`S3_END_POINT + bucket + key.`

Check the use of `S3Object` redirect location (S3 gives different endpoint url, depending on your location)

Therefore:

```
String S3_END_POINT = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"; // public files
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject("bucketname", url);
String url = S3_END_POINT + s3Object.getBucketName() + SLASH + s3Object.getKey();
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```